# Automation for mobile devices

Tags: android

Do we have any **separate tool or add on** like anything to get the x path in

android devices?

Else how can i get the values for android mobile devices?

Comment: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/ 
Have a look at this. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking about, How to inspect element in the android app, to find an element ID.

If you are using Native android application, then Android Studio is giving facility to inspect UI elements.

Once Android SDK installed, navigate to link 
***c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools*** you'll notice a batch file with name '**uiautomatorviewer.bat**'. Double-click on it to launch "Uiautomatorviewer" GUI.

If your app is using web-view then you can use Google-inspector
[Google-chrome-devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)